# Upload and download 2 or more files to/from server

Tags: android, file-upload, download

I am trying to make an app that can connect android app to the server, and I need to upload and download 2 or more files 
I found this code

```
private void doFileUpload() {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/android/data/[package]/files/productHistory";
        **String existingFileName2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/android/data/[package]/files/productStock";**
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://192.168.1.112/johnson/learn/android/";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    existingFileName));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            **dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + existingFileName2 + "\"" + lineEnd);**
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;

            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
```

The bold text is edited by me,
but it is fail, it only upload the first one

my question is 1. how to upload 2/more files with the code?
2. and how to download them?

thanks in advance

Comment: your code adds a second content-disposition header, but does not write the second file to the output stream, just the first one

Comment: I have tried it, but not work also

Comment: i mean, in the while loop writing to your connection output stream, you are just writing the first file; you need to write both, separated by boundary string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have to use a specific server, yet [Parse](http://www.parse.com) offers a sweet SDK with intuitive API to send/receive data (images in you case) to and from the server. I'd suggest you try that out if you don't want to spend to much time writing code that sends and receives data to and from a server. (and no, I don't work at Parse, just a big fan of their tools :P).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will consider it