# Android Sending Image to server

Tags: android, servlets

```
HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpParams p=new BasicHttpParams();

p.setParameter("vname",name);
p.setParameter("address", addr);
p.setParameter("age", age);
p.setParameter("contact", cnct);
p.setParameter("gender", gen);
p.setParameter("whomto", wtm);
p.setParameter("myFile", f);

HttpPost res1=new HttpPost(result);
res1.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
res1.setHeader("Content-Type","image/jpeg");

HttpResponse response1 = httpclient1.execute(res1);
HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
i1 = entity1.getContent();
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i1,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
String line1 = null;

if((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {

    sb1.append(line1);
    back=sb1.toString();
}
else{
    Log.e("GET data","null");
}
i1.close();
Log.e("GET",""+back);
```

//Server Code
private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException {

    res.setContentType("text/html");

    Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
    BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");
    final BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(new BlobKey(blobKey.getKeyString()));
    System.out.println(blobInfo.getContentType());
    if(!blobInfo.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
        blobstoreService.delete(blobInfo.getBlobKey());
        res.getWriter().println("Please Provide JPG image only");

    }
```

I am sending one image file with some other data to server.I am not getting any error or exception But when I am printing the "back",in log it is showing "The request's content type is not accepted on this URL". "f" is my image file..What is the problem?

Comment: This might be an issue in the server code, which specifies what content types it accepts for that URL. Can you share that part of the server code?

Comment: public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException {

  res.setContentType("text/html");
  
  Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
  BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");
  final BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(new BlobKey(blobKey.getKeyString()));
  System.out.println(blobInfo.getContentType());
  if(!blobInfo.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
   blobstoreService.delete(blobInfo.getBlobKey());
   res.getWriter().println("Please Provide JPG image only");
   
  }

Comment: In the previous code  i am sending the image file through f.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question as yours: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860426/upload-and-download-2-or-more-files-to-from-server/11860552#comment15776976_11860552)
It will save you the hassle of writing server side code and letting you android app send data eg. images to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the Content-Type header to two different values, neither of which is "multipart/form-data" which I believe is what you need when sending an file.

Here is an answer that should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003402/412558